# How to do multiprocessing for my specific for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, loops, multiprocessing

I have two lists `list1 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]` and `list2 = [8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20]`. I have written this for loop:

```
list3 = []

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if (i+j)%2 == 0:
           list3.append([i,j])
           break
```

How could i rewrite it with multiprocessing? I see that there is `multiprocessing.Pool` function and then there is mapping of this function. but how could i do that with my loop, which have break in it?

Comment: Why do you need multiprocessing? I'm sure `itertools`or `numpy`/`pandas` would be sufficient here

Comment: @Jab its a sample of real dataset, which is larger and more complex values in columns. but structure of dataset is the same

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do this using pandas but here's a more efficient way using `itertools.product` in a comprehension:

```
from itertools import product

list1 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
list2 = [8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20]
prev = None

list3 = [[prev := i, j] for i, j in product(list1, list2) if not (i + j) % 2 and i != prev]
```

Result:

```
[[3, 9], [4, 8], [5, 9], [6, 8], [7, 9], [8, 8]]
```

Comment: thx, and is it possible to add there tqdm?  to count how many values from list1 are already compared at the moment

Comment: what do you mean tqdm?

Comment: library ```tqdm```. i can do ```from tqdm import tqdm``` 

```list3 = []

for i in tqdm(list1):
    for j in list2:
        if (i+j)%2 == 0:
           list3.append([i,j])
           break```

Comment: and i will see progress bar counting how many values from list1 are compared with values from list2

Comment: Yes like this: `[[prev := i, j] for i, j in product(tqdm(list1), list2) if not (i + j) % 2 and i != prev]`

Comment: it seems like wrong solution. it instantly shows that all is one, even though calculations are continuing

Comment: then put the tqdm around the product

Comment: well, ```i != prev``` doesn't do the same thing here as ```break``` in my example. after my ```break```, the next value from ```list1``` will instantly be considered. but in your example, every value from list1 will be compared with each value from list2, even if condition ```(i + j) % 2 == 0 ``` will be satisfied

Comment: what i want is that once ```(i + j) % 2 == 0``` is satisfied we no longer compare that exact ```i``` with any value from ```list2```, we instantly start comparing ```i+1``` with values from ```list2```